# CSS for dl, dt and dd elements so that they appear centered and lined up as key: value

Tags: html, css, layout

I'd like to have key/values listed like this:

```
Username: myhandle
Password: lalalalalala
     Key: somevalue
```

I'm using `dl`, `dt` and `dd` html5 elements for this and trying to come up with the CSS to display these properly. I've done so at:
http://jsfiddle.net/njm84/1/

Looks good, except that I had to set a width of 50% for the left side. Problem is if the value is very long it will unnecessarily get cut off even though there's plenty of room if everything is shifted to the left. For example:

```
                                    a: some-long-value-that-extends-far-to-the-right-even-though-there's-lots-of-space-on-left
                                    b: another-value-to-the-right-even-though-there's-lots-of-space-on-left
```

Ideally it uses a kind of table layout CSS for the elements so that the above would be shifted to the left so that everything fits. The trick though is that I can't add any extra html elements. So I can't wrap the `dl` element with a `<div class="table">`.

***UPDATE***: Here's a another version of the jsfiddle that shows what I want the list of key/values to look like if one of the values is very long:
http://jsfiddle.net/njm84/4/

I had to manually change the widths (to 15%, 5% and 80%) to account for that long value, otherwise it would've wrapped.

Comment: Please update jsfiddle with your "non" working example so we all can visually see what is going on

Comment: Putting a long block of text into your fiddle seems to do what it's supposed to do: wrap to the next line.

Comment: @Diodeus - wrapping to the next line is exactly not what I want

Comment: @eberswine - I updated the question to include the situation where a value is long.

Comment: You may be better off using an actual table.

Comment: for some reason, i still don't know what you are having trouble with ? You keep on changing the css values.. On you current fiddle, what would you want to happen? Can you Photoshop or mock up what you want with a longer value ?

Comment: @eberswine - I just want to avoid wrapping text as much as possible. That's essentially the issue.

Comment: @Diodeus - you may be right about using an actual table, I just felt semantically it made more sense to have definition lists when I have a list of name/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure from your question what you're looking for but is close to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/njm84/16/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/njm84/17/)?  Here's the CSS I used:

```
body {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
dt {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}
dt:after {
    content: ":";
}
dd {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
dl {
    display: table-row;
}
dt, dd {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

A couple of notes: this depends on having a parent element you can apply `display: table` to, it doesn't have to be `body` but that was the only one available in your JSFiddle.  The other thing that will break it is if you have any markup where there are multiple `dd` elements for one `dt`.

Comment: this is exactly what I want. Problem is, I can't make the whole `body` a table. At least I assume that might cause issues with other elements in my webpages?

Comment: @at. Yeah, then like I said you'll need something else to be a wrapper element otherwise the various `dt` and `dd` will not align.  If all you have is `body` then you could try it and see what breaks, it might be easier to fix those issues than find a different working approach for this bit.

Comment: It's OK, but doesn't work for the common-case of a single `dl` parent containing multiple `dt` and `dl` children.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use `flex`:

```
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
}

dt {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

dt:after {
  content: ":";
}

dd {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0jt2uz79/1/

NOTE: this example uses multiple `dt` & `dd` contained in one `dl` - which is more semantic if the data is related to each other (as in your original "login details" example). It's a definition **list**, it allows for multiple items.